# Git hub create project with a folder fails to upload content

Tags: git, directory, project

I am trying to create a github repository for my new project, so far I have [this](https://github.com/aguzmans/TeamERP)
The problem that I am having is that I do not know why when I try to add the content of my first folder it just fails. Or well adds the folder but not the files and sub-folders inside the TeamERP folder. What I am doing is this:

```
git add TeamERP
git commit -m "Project folder"
git push
```

And what i get is what you see in the link, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

git does not track folders. Specifying a folder won't help. Try adding a file in that folder and then you will have success.

As an extra,`git commit -a` will commit all changes on all tracked files. I have moved away from using this as it is a good way to have commits with mixed purpose. If you are just now learning git, I would commit each file purposefully, until I got the hang of things.

Comment: And what if the project already exists and has a lot of files and folders inside? probably 500 or so!?

Comment: Still won't track. Add the files inside. git tracks content, folders have no content intrinsically.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually committing anything though.

you need to specify a file / folder

```
git commit TeamERP -m "Project Folder"
```

or if you are confident in all your changes, you can commit everything at once

```
git commit -a -m "Project Folder"
```